# Issue with switching navbars

Tags: html, css

Okay so currently I have 2 navbars one for desktop/large tablet and one for mobile view. I do not know how to make it switch when I get to the certain size. Here is my attempt, but it is not working.

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}

.content {
    padding: 30px;
}

.nav-main-mobile {
    display: none;
}

.nav-main {
  width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 70px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-main .logo {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.nav-main > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
    float: left;
}

.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #444;
}


.nav-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #222;
    max-height: 0;
}

.nav-content a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-content a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-sub {
    padding: 20px;
}

.nav-sub ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-sub ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

.nav-item:focus {
    background-color: #444;
}

.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
    max-height: 400px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
    transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    .nav-main {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-main-mobile {
        display: all;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTPYE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Learn HTML and CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
        
        <nav class="nav-main">
            
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-item">Home</a>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item">Materials <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <div class="nav-sub">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Text-Editors</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Web Browsers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item">Getting Started <span class="glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <div class="nav-sub">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Setting It Up</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item">Other</a>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <div class="nav-sub">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sources</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav class="nav-main-mobile">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>                
            </ul>    
        </nav>
        
        <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio.      Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. 

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. 

Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. 

Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. 


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: `display:all` is wrong. `display:block` is what you need. Close-voted as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `display: block`, not `display: all`

Comment: Correct, but for your reference "typo" questions like this should be closed, not answered. I know you don't have your close-vote hammer just yet, but keep it in mind for when you do ^^

Comment: hmm - a typo in my understanding is when somebody hits a wrong key on the keyboard and for example writes "nlock" instead of "block"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) in order to tell the browser what CSS rules you want it to apply for each specific instance.

Here is a very simple fiddle with a media query for device with a max-width of 500px, in which I override the nav background color from the original black to red.

```
/* original class */
nav{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background:#000;
}

/* when the window size is max 500px apply this rules */
@media (max-width:500px){
  nav{
    background:red;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vxyoz78x/

Hope that helps.